# How can I specialize a variadic template with a tuple of arbitrary length?

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I have the following code that should enable the use of a tuple containing shared pointers to arbitrary types:

```
#include <memory>
#include <tuple>

template<typename... Types>
using SharedPtrTuple = std::tuple<std::shared_ptr<Types>...>;

template<typename... Components>
class Processor;

template<typename... Components>
class Processor<SharedPtrTuple<Components...>>
{
  // usage of unpacking of shared pointers etc.
};
```

It works when I instantiate the Processor template with a tuple containing a single type:

```
class MyComponent {};

int main()
{
  Processor<SharedPtrTuple<MyComponent>> processor;
  return 0;
}
```

However, when I try to instantiate it with a tuple containing two or more types, it does not compile:

```
class MyComponentA {};
class MyComponentB {};

int main()
{
  Processor<SharedPtrTuple<MyComponentA, MyComponentB>> processor;
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Error   C2079   'processor' uses undefined class 'Processor<std::tuple<std::shared_ptr<MyComponentA>,std::shared_ptr<MyComponentB>>>'
```

How can I make the compiler find and use my specialization for shared pointer tuples for multiple types? I am using Visual Studio 2015 (VC12) that should have full C++11 support.

Comment: Clang and GCC both accept it, if that's of any consolation

Comment: Maybe omitting template type alias would help `class Processor<std::tuple<std::shared_ptr<Components>...>>` Note that support for c++11 is still incomplete even in VS2017.

Comment: Aside: `template<typename... Components>class Processor;` get rid of `...` here.

Comment: Indeed, you are both right, @VTT and @Yakk. If I just omit the type alias, everything works. If I reenable the type alias but omit the ellipsis in the template declaration, everything works again. Using a dependent type for `Processor`'s tuple argument (e.g., `Processor<SomethingElse::ComponentPtrTuple>` I need to omit the type alias at least in the template definition. Maybe this is some limitation of the VS2015 compiler.